# In ReactJS, can I display the SAME component multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Consider that I have a list of data.

Each row contains a username column.

The username column contains a UserName react component.

The UserName component does an ajax request in its componentDidMount() to get the actual username from an HTTP GET.

Multiple rows will contain the same username.

The problem I have is, how can I send only one ajax request for each unique username?

What is currently happening is that each UserName component is sending its own ajax request to get the username from the HTTP GET.

Note that I don't use redux so that's not a solution.

thanks

Comment: You need a better API... you should get all users with one GET request up front in the parent component.

Answer (score 4):

You can call the AJAX function in the parent component, and make sure each child component for the list of data has a key.

Your parent component should have a `usernames` array in its state.  In the parent's `componentDidMount()` function, you populate the `usernames` array.  It should only be one call, assuming you can get multiple usernames from your backend.

Then, in your `render()` function, you can use `map` to generate the `UserName` components:

```
this.state.usernames.map((un, i) => {
  return <UserName key={i} {...un} />
})};
```

The `key` is needed for uniqueness between components.

Comment: I'm almost understanding how this solves the problem.  Can you expand your explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to store data of your application not inside your presentation (last leafs in your VirtualDOM tree) components.

Solution for you - get all the data inside parent component in `componentDidMount` method and after that pass your *initial* data to each component.

Also you will have an ability to perform ajax request for each unique component, for example for button click. That need to change the state of current component, and touch the callback to update global state of parent one.

Comment: As with @cassidywilliams answer, I'm almost understanding how this solves the problem.  Can you expand your explanation please?